# What is a dexterity saving throw in the spell 'Burning Hands'?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw, difficulty-class

When the wizard fires off *[burning hands](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/burning-hands)*, the other creature has to roll a Dexterity saving throw. Is the DC the same as what's noted on my character sheet in 'features and traits'? I.e. 13

Comment: Dave, can I recommend again like Thomas already did that you read through the wizard class description in the PHB, and if possible also the Spellcasting and Combat chapters? This should take care of many of these elementary questions that you have. I understand that you are enjoying this solo adventure, still, can I also recommend to find a play group online or around where you live -- this will make learning the rules much more organic, and it also is great fun.

Comment: Please review the [How do I ask a good question?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) article. In particular, the article suggests: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: Point of clarification here, is the wizard you, or is there a different wizard casting the spell (eg. at you)?

Comment: The wizard is myself.

Answer (score 5):

The saving throw DC will be 8 + your Proficiency bonus + your Intelligence modifier.

The [Spellcasting feature of the wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#ClassFeatures) says the following:

> Intelligence is your spellcasting ability for your wizard spells, since you learn your spells through dedicated study and memorization. You use your Intelligence whenever a spell refers to your spellcasting ability. In addition, you use your Intelligence modifier when setting the saving throw DC for a wizard spell you cast and when making an attack roll with one.
>
> **Spell save DC** = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Intelligence modifier
>
> **Spell attack modifier** = your proficiency bonus + your Intelligence modifier

Answer (score 2):

The creature has to make a Dexterity *saving throw*, not a check. The DC for the Saving Throws against your spells is your **spell save DC**. This is on page 114 PHB, under the the Spellcasting Ability description of the Wizard Class

> In addition, you use your Intelligence modifier when
> setting the saving throw DC for a wizard spell you cast
> (...)
>
> **Spell save DC** = 8 + your proficiency bonus +
> your Intelligence modifier

For a level one wizard, it would be 13, if your Intelligence is 16 or 17, and it likely is what is recorded on your character sheet.

Answer (score 2):

The DC for all spells’ saving throws are defined by the class whose spell slots the spell was cast with. For example, for a wizard spell, the wizard class description includes

> #### Spellcasting Ability
>
> Intelligence is your spellcasting ability for your wizard spells, since you learn your spells through dedicated study and memorization. You use your Intelligence whenever a spell refers to your spellcasting ability.
>
> In addition, you use your Intelligence modifier when setting the saving throw DC for a wizard spell you cast and when making an attack roll with one.
>
> **Spell save DC** = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Intelligence modifier
> **Spell attack modifier** = your proficiency bonus + your intelligence modifier

<sup>(*Player’s Handbook* pg. 114)</sup>

Because this number—8 + your proficiency bonus + your Intelligence modifier—usually doesn’t change until you level up, you will most likely find it somewhere on your character sheet. **Where** it appears will vary depending on the design of the character sheet—for example, the official sheet has a dedicated spellcasting page, which has a space for this number specifically.